# ASP.Net Mobile Page App Icon On Home Screen

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to give users the ability, while viewing an asp.net website on mobile, to download an app icon on their device screen.  That way they can click on the icon and go directly to the website?

Creating a PWA seems a bit advanced for what we are trying to do.

Comment: I think its called a web shortcut, not sure if you can download one to your phone

Answer (score 0):

Anyone can add an icon to the home screen, but unfortunately, you can't do it through the website, only through the browser app.

PWA is actually very simple to set up and you can easily make it so that it behaves exactly like a shortcut in less than 10 minutes on your existing app with just a couple of lines of code.

You can follow this instruction (start with step 2 by adding `WebEssentials.AspNetCore.PWA` through NuGet): [PWA in Asp.Net Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/progressive-web-app-pwa-in-asp-net-core/)

After you followed through you have to modify a couple of things though. Let me walk you through it. These changes will make your PWA perform like a website shortcut.

**1.** Go to `wwwroot/manifest.json` here and modify the `display` parameter. This will make your PWA behave just like a regular website when it's "installed" (instead of opening it up in a separate window on mobile devices and desktops).

```
"display": "browser"
```

**2.** After you've done this we want to set the PWA strategy. Go to `Program.cs` or `Startup.cs` (depends on which .net version are you) and here modify these lines (you have done this in step 4 of the tutorial link I posted):

```cs
builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddProgressiveWebApp(new PwaOptions
{
  Strategy = ServiceWorkerStrategy.Minimal
});
```

Basically just add `PwaOptions()` into `AddProgressiveWebApp()`.

There are several different strategies you can use, but for your case minimal is the best. This way the website will behave just like a website and not a true PWA. You can always "upgrade" your app and introduce proper PWA later on.

And it's as easy as that. You are done, your app now has a PWA option, that will behave exactly like a website shortcut. And all this can be done in under 10 minutes.

Hope this helps :D